# How to prevent Nautilus from launching when I press Super key?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop.

The problem is when I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key without any additional combination to open the dash board, Nautilus  is opened too. This is really weird and awful and prevents me from using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key at all.